# Is there one word for people who always keep others above themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, expressions, adjectives

For people who go an extra mile to make others comfortable, be it friends, family, etc.
I need an adjective or a noun, most probably one word, that can describe people who always keep others above or ahead of themselves.

Comment: You can take your pick from: _obliging, helpful, accommodating, considerate, indulgent_  and other synonyms.

Comment: Perhaps a **kindly soul**.

Comment: We need more context. Answers could range from *altruistic* to *subservient*.

Comment: Thank you all! The context is 'a quality of a person in a positive way, words which might describe his/her nature in a way that he/she is not self centered, tries to make things more comfortable for others, thinks about the people around him and tries to change things according to them... Altruistic suits better than subservient. By doing all this, the person doesn't come out as a person with low aspirations or submissive.

Comment: what about **selfless**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the comments, **"altruistic"** seems to be the word you're looking for.

> - **altruism** (noun)  "feelings and behavior that show a desire to help other people and a lack of selfishness"
>
> e.g. "I ​doubt whether her ​motives for ​donating the ​money are altruistic - she's ​probably ​looking for ​publicity."  [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altruism)

Depending on context, especially if it doesn't involve any self-sacrifice, "helpful" may also fit.

> - helpful (adj) - "willing to help other people" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use complaisant, charitable, altruistic, humane, accommodating, and maybe liberal or compassionate. Those would be pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

*Self-sacrificing* if the person doesn't overdo it.  Otherwise, *kitchen martyr* or *doormat*.